# AVG is not taking null values into consideration

Tags: google-bigquery

I have loaded the following test data:

```
name,   age,gender
"John", 33,m
"Sam",  33,m
"Julie",33,f
"Jimbo",, m
```

with schema: `name:STRING,age:INTEGER,gender:STRING` and I have confirmed that the Jimbo row shows a null for column "age" in the BigQuery Browser Tool > mydataset > Details > Preview section.

When I run this query :

```
SELECT AVG(age) FROM [peterprivatedata.testpeople]
```

I get 24.75 which is incorrect. I expected 33 because the [documentation for AVG](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-reference#aggfunctions) says "Rows with a NULL value are not included in the calculation."

Am I doing something wrong or is this a known bug? (I don't know if there's a public issues list to check). What's the simplest workaround to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug where we coerce null numeric values to to 0 on import. We're currently working on a fix. These values *do* however, show up as not not defined (which for various reasons is different from null), so you can check for IS_EXPLICITLY_DEFINED. For example:

```
SELECT sum(if(is_explicitly_defined(numeric_field), numeric_field, 0)) / 
       sum(if(is_explicitly_defined(numeric_field), 1, 0)) 
    AS my_avg FROM your_table
```

Alternately, you could use another column to represent is_null. Then the query would look like:

```
    SELECT sum(if(numeric_field_is_null, 0, numeric_field)) / 
       sum(if(numeric_field_is_null, 0, 1)) 
    AS my_avg FROM your_table
```

Comment: I know you're a developer on the team but I don't see that the null numeric values have been coerced to 0 on import. For example, the details tab "Preview" feature shows them as null and IS_EXPLICITLY_DEFINED(age) evaluates to false for that row.

Comment: Using your suggested workarounds as a start I came up with one that requires no additional import or columns and seems to do the job: sum(if(IS_EXPLICITLY_DEFINED(age),age,0)) / 
         sum(if(IS_EXPLICITLY_DEFINED(age),1,0)) as my_avg

Comment: OK that is good to know... My original answer looked something like what you came up with yourself, but then I thought you must be hitting  this value-coercion bug so I tried to give a workaround for that instead.

Comment: Thanks. So I take it there is a different bug related to AVG and null and that my workaround will suffice? If you update your answer I will be able to accept it as answered for me.